# http mock for dom document

Tags: httpcalloutmock, httpresponse

I am using http mock method for testing responses.

But as one of the class expects DOM document and use `response.getBodyDocument()`.

Usually, I used to insert sample response for http mock. I am not sure how to prepare for Response as Dom Document which will return xml.

Because when I run the test class, when it reaches `dom.XmlNode envelope = resDoc.getRootElement();` , cannot move on to another step. So seem like I need to change my response to be readable as DOM.

Below is my usual approach.

```
 global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) 
    {
        //fake callout
        String url = 'http://xxx.yyy';

        System.assertEquals(url, req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        String resInfo = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
                    + '<blahblah> ....</blahblah>';
        res.setBody(resInfo);
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
```

Class which will use response and parse as DOM.

```
        res = http.send(req);
                if (res.getStatusCode() == 200)
                {        
                    dom.Document resDoc = res.getBodyDocument();
                     dom.XmlNode envelope = resDoc.getRootElement();
                        ...
                }
```

How should I return the response which can be parsed as DOM document?

Comment: From one of the real webservice just take the data and copy paste in the response .That should help.As exact two level deeper with lot of attributes dummy data creation may be pain.So inspect real data response and copy paste

Comment: I did copy and paste the sample response into String resInfo. But I don't know why another class couldn't pick up at line dom.XmlNode envelope = resDoc.getRootElement();

Comment: hi , which apex class are you talking? I already added the class that read the response. Please let me know more.